# Registers and Private Buffer

Tags: opencl

What is the differences between registers and private memory in openCL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physically, registers are on-chip and thus close to the cores. Private memory is apportioned from the DRAM, which is pretty far from the core. By close and far, we are referring to latency here. A read from register might take 1-10 clock cycles, while a read from DRAM might take 200-400 clock cycles.

Also, as a programmer you cannot really address a particular register (unless you do assembly programming). What registers will be used to execute your kernel is decided by the compiler or the processor at runtime. But, you can address specific location of private memory as needed.

Comment: thanks a lot for the replay. How can we access these memories, ok we access private by __private but how about registers.

Comment: Megharaj: The answer to that can be found in my reply: you cannot access registers from OpenCL. The registers used for your kernel is decided by the compiler or by the hardware at runtime (just like with any other language).

Comment: I think this might be the reason for my problem in one of my questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885880/effect-of-private-memory-in-opencl.

Comment: in some article on net i have seen that in OpenCL kernel if we take variables without __private by default they will be private memory, but is it like compiler use registers for some variable when it exceeds than registers available it will use private memory ?

Comment: Megharaj: Yes. When register spilling happens, private memory might be used to handle that.

Comment: There is confusion here between the OpenCL address space, which is specified by "__private", and the physical memory where the variable is allocated. A __private variable will typically be allocated in registers on a GPU, but may be spilled over to off-chip memory if there is not enough register capacity (e.g. "CUDA local" memory on NVidia). There is no such physical thing as "private memory".