# opencl asked about size of type Memory Model

Tags: memory, model, opencl, global, local

how can know the maximum size of all type memory model for opencl (gpu & cpu)

Global Memory,Constant Memory,Local Memory,Private Memory.

and what of this type is the faster ???

Answer (score 0):

"All of the memory" isn't really a relevant phrase for opencl. You use devices separately, and you poll them for their specs separately. use clGetDeviceInfo and pass in the constant/code you want to ask from the driver. Read more about this here: [clGetDeviceInfo](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)

If you want to know about total memory, you need to sum up the values for the memory types you ask about.

As for the speed of memory types, I answered a related question about this not too long ago: [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21882381/1152356).

Comment: thanks ,clinfo for my gpu and cpu 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2fr827ikcrjvoe0/new%20%204.txt