# Non deterministic behaviour of OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

Consider the following OpenCL kernel. It is a MWE which came out from a long simplification process. Of course it does not make sense to have such a kernel, but this is not the point. It is guaranteed that `MAX_ORDER >= num_fields` and in particular `MAX_ORDER=15` (this is passed to `clBuildProgram` as compile time constant via `-D`).

```
__kernel void MWE_kernel(__global const double* const x,
                         __global const double* alpha, const int num_fields,
                         __global double* const restrict result,
                         __local double* const restrict result_local)
{
    const int id          = get_global_id(0);
    const int global_size = get_global_size(0);

    double sum[MAX_ORDER];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
        sum[i] = 0.0;
    
    double sum_sc=0.0;

    for (unsigned int id_mem = id; id_mem < 128 * num_fields; id_mem += global_size) {
        const int alpha_idx = id_mem / 128;
        //sum[0] += 3.0;
        sum[alpha_idx] += 3.0;
        sum_sc += 3.0;
        /*
        if (id == 8){
            printf("sum[%d]=%f   sum_sc=%f\n", alpha_idx, sum[alpha_idx], sum_sc);
        }
        */
    }
    
    if(id == 8){
        result[0] = sum[0];
        result[1] = sum_sc;
    }
}
```

which I enqueue on a GPU device (Device Name: `Intel(R) Gen9 HD Graphics NEO`) with `local_size=64` and `global_size=64` and `num_fields=1`.

The weird behaviour I am experiencing, which I cannot explain, is that, if I try to fill the `sum` private array using `alpha_idx` as index, then this is not working for some threads, in the sense that the `sum` entry is not increased. The first thread that shows such a behaviour is the number 8, for which the last `if`-clause sets `result[0] = 0` and `result[1]=6`, as I can check on the host.

#### Facts I noticed debugging:

- Setting `MAX_ODER=1` (possible in this example, since `num_fields=1`), makes the weird behaviour disappear (`result[0]` becomes 6). However, for `1<MAX_ORDER<21` nothing changes. Surprisingly enough, `MAX_ORDER>=22` changes the kernel behaviour and I get `result[0]=6`.
- Varying `local_size` and/or `global_size` does not change anything, unless `local_size` is decreased to 8 or less (see next bullet).
- Reducing the `local_size` with which I enqueue the kernel to 8 makes the weird behaviour disappear (in the above example trivially, since there is no thread number 8 any more, but in the more complex complete version I then get the expected result).
- Using online tools like [this one](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2013-05-13/verify-your-opencl-kernel-online/) does not spot any problem.

#### Questions:

1. Do you have any idea that explains the behaviour I am experiencing? Can you reproduce such a behaviour?
2. Is the private memory usage safe? Or the `sum` array declaration is somehow critical?
3. If I am not doing anything wrong, is such a behaviour a (GPU) compiler bug!?

Comment: Isn't `alpha_idx` the same value for blocks of all 128 workitems (e.g. global id 0..127) due to integer division (id_mem/128). They all try and increment the same address leading to read-modify-write races.

Comment: @Tim As far as I understood, since `sum` is declared in the work item private memory, each work item has its own copy of the `sum` variable. You're right saying that `alpha_idx` in the above example is always 0, but I think the memory being incremented is not the same. In any case, the race condition would still be there using `sum[0]` with 0 hard-coded, isn't it? Am I mistaken?

Comment: You're correct, I misread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more work on this issue, I might have a kind of explanation to what is happening, although this is not really a proof, but rather few more facts.

The starting point is the strange behaviour of having the kernel behave as expected either reducing the `local_size` with which it is run or enlarging the size of the private memory array `sum`. How does the OpenCL compiler handle private memory? Reading into the [AMD OpenCL User Guide](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_User_Guide.pdf#G17.1059983), I found the following sentence at page 25-26 (emphasis is mine).

> The data in private memory is first placed in registers. If more private memory is used than can be placed in registers, or **dynamic indexing is used on private arrays**, the overflow data is placed (spilled) into scratch memory. Scratch memory is a private subset of global memory, so performance can be dramatically degraded if spilling occurs.

It is curious that there is no definition of what is meant by *dynamic indexing* in the full guide. However, I found [an interesting article](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/fast-dynamic-indexing-private-arrays-cuda/) by nVIDIA people, which is pretty much explaining the idea. *Dynamic indexing* happens when **the compiler can't resolve array indices to constants**. In such a case, it is then forced not to use registers any more.

In the present kernel, dynamic indexing is forced by using `alpha_idx` in setting `sum`. This is somehow the breaking point, while putting there a `sum[0]` makes the kernel work as expected, but it changes also from dynamic to static indexing!

To check even further this guess, I tried to implement the kernel storing the private `sum` in the local memory. This can be achieved with a buffer in the local memory of which only a given portion is accessed by each work item. Interestingly enough, doing so the kernel works as expected and the weird behaviour is not seen any more.

At this point why the code was also fixed either by reducing the `local_size` to 8 or something smaller or setting a value of `MAX_ORDER` larger than 21 remains unclear. In [this interesting SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42113363/14967071) the author writes

> If going from local to private doesn't do good, you should decrease local thread group size from 256 to 64 for example. So more private registers available per thread.

that is basically saying that reducing the `local_size` makes the compiler being able to handle variables in private memory differently.

All in all I am having the feeling that the compiler on the used GPU (`Intel(R) Gen9 HD Graphics NEO`, actually not really a GPGPU) is doing something weird handling the dynamic indexing in the kernel. What exactly, I do not really know, but **it really sounds to me like a compiler bug**. On one hand, a smaller `local_size` value hides the problem because - just a guess - having more memory per work group, the compiler bug is not hit. On the other hand, increasing `MAX_ORDER` makes also the problem disappear because - again just guess - the compiler does something different (e.g. using a different strategy being the kernel requiring much more memory), and the bug is not hit.

To support even further all this chain of thoughts, I tested the original code on a real GPGPU. Running the code on a AMD Radeon Instinct MI50 nothing weird occurs.

Comment: "Dynamic indexing happens when the compiler can't resolve array indices to constants. In such a case, it is then forced not to use registers any more." - it's good to remember that 1) these are vendor-specific implementation details, 2) the guide you linked is from 2013, 3) in your code the array is fixed (and small) size. I wouldn't call that statement about dynamic indexing true on Intel platform (or in general).

Comment: "reducing the local_size makes the compiler being able to handle variables in private memory differently" - yes. On GPU, private memory (registers) are fixed & usually quite limited, so scheduling work in smaller work-groups means more private memory available per work-item.

Comment: @mogu Thanks for the comments, they're surely useful for future reference. Exactly in this spirit I wrote up my answer. Hopefully some other user can get inspired. I stopped debugging the problem, given the above findings.